# session timeout redirect to login java maven project

Tags: java, maven, web.xml

short Question:

can i redirect to the login page via web.xml?

I have set a session timeout in the web.xml but i cant find anything related to the redirect thats as simple as the problem sounds :D

```
if (yes)
{
  how
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use this JSP header :

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=session.getMaxInactiveInterval()%>" url="redirect URL" />`

`getMaxInactiveInterval()` returns the timeout interval.
So once session times out, control will be redirected to the mentioned URL